# How to dynamically set link to cells in a range and populate destination with adjacent value(s) (GAS)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

I got the following piece of code setting the link to the first cell only in the specified range.

```
function addHyperlink() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var vGeral = ss.getSheetByName("Visão Geral");//where the range whose cells will have a link is
  var eSheet = ss.getSheetByName("EditarItem").getSheetId();//destination sheet
  var rng = vGeral.getRange(18,2,vGeral.getLastRow(),3).getValues();//range where values to be brought to dest sheet are
  var destCell = ss.getSheetByName("EditarItem").getRange("X4").getA1Notation;//destination cell
  var rownum = vGeral.getRange("A18:A").getRow();//get rows where setValue(hyperlink) will occur
  for (var a = 1; a < rng.length; a++) {
    Logger.log(rng[a][0]);
    if (rng[a][0] != '') {
      var code = rng[a][1];
      var item = rng[a][2];
      var version = rng[a][3];
      vGeral.getRange(rownum,1).setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheetId/edit#gid=2121018263&range=X4:AA4";"Editar")');
    }
  } 
}
```

How would I go about getting values from columns B and C and populating the destination cells when I click on the links generated above?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `rng[a][3]` `var version = rng[a][3];`

There is only 3 columns in rng:

```
var rng = vGeral.getRange(18,2,vGeral.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
```

and rownum is always 18:

```
vGeral.getRange(rownum,1).setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheetId/edit#gid=2121018263&range=X4:AA4";"Editar")');
```